# How to search Internet for an author if the name contains a monogram?

Tags: search, windows-search

I have problem searching for authors on a lot of websites if the author's name contains monogram.
Here's the example:
If I try to find every topics on a forum about "H. G. Wells", then I type "H. G. Wells" (with or without quotes) into the search field. The search results contain hundreds of useless topics about other authors, such as Liz Wells and Victorie Wells. 
The search function finds all the other names containing "Wells", and not only H. G. Wells that I'm interested in. 
Google search is smarter. It only finds the stuff I'm looking for, but now I'm talking about different sites, forums mostly.

How can I exclude everything else from the search results?

How I can search for "H.G. Wells" without finding "Liz Wells" and "Victoria Wells"?

Comment: That's specific to the search engine.  Typically, putting something in quotes is the way to do it.  At least in Google, prefixing it with a plus sign means "must contain".

Comment: A lot of search engines ignore short words. All of them ignore punctuation, including Google, even inside "", but "h g wells" is going to get you further than anything else. If you get a lot of Lizzies, then "h g wells" -liz